# Lyapunov inequality and $L^p$ interpolation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I am trying to prove the this called "Lyapunov's inequality":

$$\big\||f_0|^{p_0(1-\theta)/p}|f_1|^{p_1\theta/p}\big\|^p_p\leq\|f_0\|^{(1-\theta)p_0}_{p_0}\|f_1\|^{p_1\theta}_{p_1}$$

which is stated on Wikipedia [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).

I do not even understand which are $f_0$ and $f_1$ and to which $L^p$ space they belong.

Does anyone have any reference on this particular inequality (preferably with a proof)?

Comment: $f_0$ and $f_1$ are any two measurable functions you want, like $f$ and $g$ in the article you linked. In fact you can directly deduce Lyapunov's inequality from Hölder's inequality with a certain choice of $f$, $g$, $p$, and $q$, it might be a neat little exercise to try and find which. I don't know of references to it right now, but if it can help your search, this is a well-known example of what are called *interpolation inequalities*.

Comment: It seems that the assumptions are $f_0\in L_{p_0}$ and $f_1\in L_{p_1}$.

Comment: I am sure thus has been asked before at MSE. The general procedure is something like $$\Big(|f_0|^{p_0(1-\theta)/p}|f_1|^{p_1\theta/p}\Big)^p=|f_0|^{p_0(1-\theta)}|f_1|^{p_1\theta}$$

If $f_j\in L_{p_j}$, then $|f_j|^{p_ja}\in L_{1/a}$ for all $0<a<1$. Apply Holder's to get $\int|f_0|^{p_0(1-\theta)}|f_1|^{p_1\theta}\leq\Big(\int|f_0|^{p_0}\Big)^{1-\theta}\Big(\int|f_1|^{p_`}\Big)^{\theta}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mittens has given all the details in his comments, but it seems that a more formal treatment is wanted.

**Proposition.** Let $(X, {\mathcal S}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $p_0, p_1, p\in [1, \infty)$, and $\theta\in (0, 1)$. Let $f_0\in L^{p_0}(X)$ and $f_1\in L^{p_1}(X)$. Then
$$
\big\| |f_0|^{\frac{p_0(1-\theta)}{p}}\cdot |f_1|^{\frac{p_1\theta}{p}}\big\|_p^p\leq
\big\|f_0\big\|_{p_0}^{p_0(1-\theta)}\big\|f_1\big\|_{p_1}^{p_1\theta}.
$$

**Proof.** Noting that $\|f\|_p^p=\int |f|^p$ and applying the Holder inequality by $(1-\theta)+\theta=1$, we have
\begin{align}
\big\| |f_0|^{\frac{p_0(1-\theta)}{p}}\cdot |f_1|^{\frac{p_1\theta}{p}}\big\|_p^p
&= \int |f_0|^{p_0(1-\theta)} |f_1|^{p_1\theta}\\
&\leq \Big(\int \big(|f_0|^{p_0(1-\theta)}\big)^{\frac{1}{1-\theta}}\Big)^{1-\theta} \Big(\int \big(|f_1|^{p_1\theta}\big)^{\frac{1}{\theta}}\Big)^{\theta}\\
&=\Big(\int |f_0|^{p_0}\Big)^{1-\theta} \Big(\int |f_1|^{p_1}\big)^{\theta}\\
&=\big\|f_0\big\|_{p_0}^{p_0(1-\theta)} \big\|f_1\big\|_{p_1}^{p_1\theta}.
\end{align}

**Interpolation.** In the Wikepedia page you refer to, only in the next step, we ask $1\leq p_0<p_1<\infty$, $p=(1-\theta)p_0 + \theta p_1$, and $f_0=f_1=f$ to get
\begin{equation}\label{finite}
\|f\|_p^p\leq \|f\|_{p_0}^{p_0(1-\theta)}\|f\|_{p_1}^{p_1\theta}.
\end{equation}
Then it is concluded that if $f\in L^{p_0}\cap L^{p_1}$, then $f\in L^p$ for all $p_0<p<p_1$.

**A little more.** It is easy to show that the interpolation also holds when $p_1=\infty$. That is, if $f\in L^{p_0}\cap L^\infty$, then $f\in L^p$ for all $p_0<p<\infty$.

The proof is simply that by $|f|\leq \|f\|_\infty$ a.e., we have
$$
\int |f|^p = \int |f|^{p_0} |f|^{p-p_0} \leq \|f\|_\infty^{p-p_0}\int |f|^{p_0}.
$$
In the norm notation, this is
$$
\|f\|_p^p\leq \|f\|_{p_0}^{p_0}\|f\|_\infty^{p-p_0}.
$$
This matches the above $p_1<\infty$ case, by letting $\theta=0$, and noting $p_1\theta = p - (1-\theta)p_0$ from $p=(1-\theta)p_0 + \theta p_1$.

Comment: Three aggies, does the result hold in for spaces $L^{p_i}(\Omega)$ or $L^{p_i}(\mathbb R^n)$?

Comment: Sure. It holds for any measure space, no condition on the measure being finite or even $\sigma$-finite. (For example, a bounded $\Omega$ would have finite Lebesgue measure, and ${\mathbb R}^n$ would have $\sigma$-finite measure.) The results hold in all cases.